# Arraylist Java Binding errors

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to create my own registry for a school project.

I would like to have

```
1
room, room
2
room, room
hall, hall
3
room, room
hall, hall
dorm, dorm
```

But all I am getting is

```
1
room,room
2
room,hall
hall,hall
3
room,dorm
hall,dorm
dorm,dorm
```

So somehow the the facility reference got changed somewhere but i have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone help?

These are my codes.

```
public class registry {
static List<registryRecord> register = new ArrayList<registryRecord>();
public static boolean bind(String name, facility ref){
    for(registryRecord r:register){
        if(r.name.equals(name)) //check if the name is already binded
            return false;
    }
    registryRecord newRecord = new registryRecord(name, ref);
    register.add(newRecord);
    for (registryRecord r:register){
        System.out.println(r.name +","+ r.ref.name);
    }
    return true;
}

public class registryRecord {
String name;
facility ref;
public registryRecord(String name, facility ref){
    this.name = name;
    this.ref = ref;
}

public class server {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{  
    facility room = new facility("room");
    System.out.println(1);
    boolean test = registry.bind("room", room);
    facility hall = new facility("hall");
    System.out.println(2);
    boolean test2 = registry.bind("hall", hall);
    facility dorm = new facility("dorm");
    System.out.println(3);
    registry.bind("dorm", dorm);
}
public class facility {
    public static String name;
    static List<booking> bookings;

    public facility(String name){
        this.name=name;
        this.bookings = new ArrayList<booking>();
    }
}
```

Comment: One general info : Its a bad practice to use small letter as the Class name initial.

Comment: Can you post the `facility` code too? It looks like you have a `static` name field in there.

Comment: Roger that. Thank you

Comment: Apart from the obvious mistake, having a public field in a class is a bad idea. Make them private. And for God's Sake, follow the Java Naming Conventions. Class names start with upper case letters.

Comment: Your code not looking fine syntactically strange about how you get even run it.

Comment: @RohitJain changed all to upper case. Can you explain more about the public field?

Comment: @FenilShah only posted part of it. Thats why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, since `name` is `static` in `facility`, it is shared between all instances. This means that it gets overwritten each time you create a new instance.

Just remove `static` from both your fields, and your program should work fine.

Comment: You're very welcome. As @RohitJain mentions in the comments above, it would probably be a good idea to read up on Java coding standards.